# Counting time after an if condition, then doing a while until certain time is reached

Tags: c#, if-statement, time, while-loop, do-while

I'm using C# within  Visual Studio.

I'm trying to start counting time when an if condition is fulfilled, then do something within a while loop while the counter still hasn't reached a certain time.

To illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
if(condition)
{
  //start counting time

  while(time < 5) 
  {
    //perform action
  }
}
```

The code is a bit more complicated, but I would know how to apply it from that example. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by time? the clock or the number?

Comment: Without knowing what the calling code looks like and what happens inside the loop, it's not possible to provide an answer that can be assured of being the best answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your question right, but this is how to do something for a specific amount of time:

```
if(condition)
{
  Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

  while(watch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: This will work. But some notes: 1) it would be better to initialize the `TimeSpan` for the purpose of comparison once, saving the value in a local variable, instead of calling `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)` every loop iteration; 2) without more context, it's possible that the basic approach the OP illustrates is just plain wrong, e.g. blocking a UI thread for the whole time period while it runs this tight loop. The OP really needs to provide better details to get a good answer.